# Adding a Timeout Function to jXHR.js

Tags: jquery, jsonp

How can i add a timeout function to jXHR.js available from: http://mulletxhr.com/

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using jQuery for the Ajax calls if have it available anyways?

Comment: Am making cross domain calls for apps and jquery ajax is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It has `SETTIMEOUT`, see its source code here:

http://mulletxhr.com/jXHR.js

It us used there in `send` function. Search for `send:` there.

**Update:**

Modify this function in the `jXHR.js` file:

```
    send:function(){
            SETTIMEOUT(function(){
                scriptElem = doc.createElement("script");
                scriptElem.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                scriptElem.onload = scriptElem.onreadystatechange = function(){handleScriptLoad.call(scriptElem);};
                scriptElem.setAttribute("src",script_url);
                doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElem);
            },60000);
            fireReadyStateChange(2);
        },
```

See I have added `60000` in above code for 60 seconds, you can modify that as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. What value is it set to and where do i change it. Thanks

Comment: I would like the send function to timeout after 60 seconds.

Comment: The script now waits for 60 secs before executing. What i wanted was for it to run for 60 secs.